# resque-web fails to start with a 500 Server Error 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, open-uri

I'm following the configuration guidelines for installing [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). I'm met with a (OpenURI::HTTPError). I'm using RVM 1.9.2-p180, rails 3.0.6, and [POW](http://pow.cx/).'resque-web' fails to start with a 500 Server Error. What the heck is going on here?

To replicate problem:

1. Start redis with $ `redis-server`
2. Start a worker with `$ VVERBOSE=1 QUEUE=file_serve rake environment resque:work`
3. Try to start Resque-Web with: `RAILS_ENV=development resque-web config/initializers/resque.rb`

config/resque.yml

```
development: localhost:6379
test: localhost:6379
staging: localhost:6379
fi: localhost:6379
```

initializers/resque.rb:

```
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

require 'resque'
# require 'yaml'

unless defined?($redis)
  $redis = Redis.new($redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379))
end

Resque.redis = $redis
```

Terminal:

```
     master ~/projects/MyApp $ RAILS_ENV=development resque-web config/initializers/resque.rb
[2011-05-20 11:42:48 -0700] Starting 'resque-web'...
/Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:346:in `open_http': 500 Internal Server Error  (OpenURI::HTTPError)
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:769:in `buffer_open'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:671:in `open'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:142:in `port_open?'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:159:in `check_for_running'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:104:in `start'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/vegas-0.1.8/lib/vegas/runner.rb:77:in `initialize'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/resque-1.16.1/bin/resque-web:13:in `new'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/resque-1.16.1/bin/resque-web:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/resque-web:19:in `load'
    from /Users/boris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/resque-web:19:in `<main>'
```

Redis-server (I am connecting an extra client when I hit localhost:6379.

```
[33324] 20 May 11:02:08 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 932400 bytes in use
[33324] 20 May 11:02:12 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:53028
[33324] 20 May 11:02:13 - DB 0: 7 keys (0 volatile) in 8 slots HT.
[33324] 20 May 11:02:13 - 2 clients connected (0 slaves), 942976 bytes in use
[33324] 20 May 11:02:18 - DB 0: 7 keys (0 volatile) in 8 slots HT.
```

Initializers/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

Terminal: (proof of $redis)

```
> $redis
#<Redis client v2.2.0 connected to redis://localhost:6379/0 (Redis v2.2.5)>
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > $redis.set('pepper', 'bacon')   #=> "OK"
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > $redis.get('pepper')   #=> "bacon"
```

Comment: somewhat same issue, did you resolved this?

Comment: I had the same error message (500 internal server error) but for a different reason: there was already an instance of `resque-web` running on its default port of 5678. `resque-web -K` to kill the existing process solved this error message for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
$redis = Redis.new($redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379))
```

Try just doing:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```